# Date input from EditText

Tags: java, android, date, android-edittext

I'm trying to input date values from an editText, but i keep making error, what i should do?

```
    EditText DataI = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.DataI);
    EditText DataF = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.DataF);   

        calendar1.setTime(DataI);
        calendar2.setTime(DataF);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
SimpleDateFormat format=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
calendar1.setTime(format.parse(DataI.getText().toString());
calendar2.setTime(format.parse(DataF.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

There are components in Android API that're created for date-time input:

[Read here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html)

I think it's more appropriate to use the than an EditText